# ISCP-DHCP server on Ubuntu 20.04, connect to RaspberryPi

Tags: raspberrypi, dhcp, static-ip

I have failed to connect to my raspberryPi using a static IP and over my existing wireless network. My next attempt is to set up a DHCP server on my Ubuntu machine. I use several tutorials ([tut1](https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/ubuntu/dhcp-server-on-ubuntu), [tut2_german](https://www.howtoforge.de/anleitung/wie-man-einen-dhcp-server-unter-ubuntu-20-04-installiert-und-konfiguriert/)) but am unable to get the server even running. My installation steps:

*Installed isc-dhcp server*

> sudo apt install isc-dhcp-server

*Set wired connection now to manual*

[image]

*Configure dhcp-server*

> nano /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

```
# a simple /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
authoritative;

subnet 192.168.4.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
 range 192.168.4.100 192.168.4.200;
 option routers 192.168.4.1;
 option domain-name-servers 192.168.4.1, 192.168.4.2;
 option domain-name "rpi.example";
}

host archmachine {
hardware ethernet b8:27:eb:4d:6c:1c;
fixed-address 192.168.4.20;
}
```

*add interface for dhcp-server (a ethernet-USB dongle)*

> nano /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server

```
# 
INTERFACES="enx9cebe82d8042"
```

*various commands to start\restart ics-dhcp*

```
sudo systemctl start isc-dhcp-server.service
sudo systemctl enable isc-dhcp-server.service
sudo systemctl restart isc-dhcp-server.service
```

*Result*

> sudo systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service

yields an error I am unable to decipher

```
● isc-dhcp-server.service - ISC DHCP IPv4 server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/isc-dhcp-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-04-24 19:00:27 CEST; 5s ago
       Docs: man:dhcpd(8)
    Process: 114920 ExecStart=/bin/sh -ec      CONFIG_FILE=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf;      if [ -f /etc/ltsp/dhcpd.conf ]; then CONFIG_FILE=/etc/ltsp/dhcpd.conf; >
   Main PID: 114920 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 24 19:00:27 MEpc dhcpd[114920]: 
Apr 24 19:00:27 MEpc dhcpd[114920]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
Apr 24 19:00:27 MEpc dhcpd[114920]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
Apr 24 19:00:27 MEpc dhcpd[114920]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
Apr 24 19:00:27 MEpc dhcpd[114920]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
Apr 24 19:00:27 MEpc dhcpd[114920]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging.
Apr 24 19:00:27 MEpc dhcpd[114920]: 
Apr 24 19:00:27 MEpc dhcpd[114920]: exiting.
Apr 24 19:00:27 MEpc systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 24 19:00:27 MEpc systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The wired connection in the taskmenu also keeps trying to connect. The result is also a 'Wired network failed' and after a few attempts disconnects by itself.

Changing the "Wired-Setup" to 'Manual' resulted in a connected status. But I am still unsure of the correct settings in this GUI or if it is ignored when I change network settings in various files

[image]

**UPDATE**

Some sites suggests editing /network/interfaces. Since I do not have eth0 I changed it to

```
auto enx9cebe82d8042  
iface enx9cebe82d8042 inet dhcp
```

I changed the Wired settings to 'Manual' and at least it is now connected, instead if repeatedly trying to connect to something. Also I could take a look into my /var/syslog

```
pr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc dhcpd[127702]: Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc dhcpd[127702]: All rights reserved.
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc dhcpd[127702]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc dhcpd[127702]: Config file: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc sh[127702]: Config file: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc sh[127702]: Database file: /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc sh[127702]: PID file: /run/dhcp-server/dhcpd.pid
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc dhcpd[127702]: Database file: /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc sh[127702]: Wrote 0 leases to leases file.
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc dhcpd[127702]: PID file: /run/dhcp-server/dhcpd.pid
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc dhcpd[127702]: Wrote 0 leases to leases file.
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc dhcpd[127702]: 
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc sh[127702]: No subnet declaration for enx9cebe82d8042 (192.168.4.5).
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc sh[127702]: ** Ignoring requests on enx9cebe82d8042.  If this is not what
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc sh[127702]:    you want, please write a subnet declaration
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc sh[127702]:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc sh[127702]:    to which interface enx9cebe82d8042 is attached. **
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc sh[127702]: Not configured to listen on any interfaces!
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc sh[127702]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc sh[127702]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc sh[127702]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc sh[127702]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc sh[127702]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging.
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc sh[127702]: exiting.
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc dhcpd[127702]: No subnet declaration for enx9cebe82d8042 (192.168.4.5).
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc dhcpd[127702]: ** Ignoring requests on enx9cebe82d8042.  If this is not what
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc dhcpd[127702]:    you want, please write a subnet declaration
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc dhcpd[127702]:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc dhcpd[127702]:    to which interface enx9cebe82d8042 is attached. **
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc dhcpd[127702]: 
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc dhcpd[127702]: 
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc dhcpd[127702]: Not configured to listen on any interfaces!
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc dhcpd[127702]: 
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc dhcpd[127702]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc dhcpd[127702]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc dhcpd[127702]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc dhcpd[127702]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc dhcpd[127702]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging.
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc dhcpd[127702]: 
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc dhcpd[127702]: exiting.
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 25 07:26:32 stefanpc systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Here this lines stood out

> No subnet declaration for enx9cebe82d8042 (192.168.4.5)
> ** Ignoring requests on enx9cebe82d8042. If this is not what A you  want, please write a subnet declaration  in your dhcpd.conf file for
> the network segment

This would suggest, that the USB dongle is not allowed. Using *ip a* results in following interfaces

```
: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:21:5c:b6:21:e6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.175/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0
       valid_lft 84869sec preferred_lft 84869sec
    inet6 fe80::a6f6:95e5:e050:d8a/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
14: enx9cebe82d8042: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9c:eb:e8:2d:80:42 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.4.5/24 brd 192.168.4.255 scope global noprefixroute enx9cebe82d8042
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9eeb:e8ff:fe2d:8042/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Here number 14 is the external dongle with the presumed name "enx9cebe82d8042".

Are USB-Ethernet dongles not allowed to host DHCP-Servers?
Where do I declare the interface in dhcpd.conf?

Comment: Read `man systemd-dnsmasq dnsmasq`. Ubuntu already has a DHCP/DNS server. It already owns port 53. Also, the `ExecStart=` line in the `.service` file looks funny.

Comment: The config file does not go in `/etc/default` it goes in `/etc/dhcp`.

Comment: I have no influence over the 'ExecStart=' statetment. Then I will try it with dnsmasq. Do I need to remove the ics-dhcp or only stop it?

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages **you** got on **your system**. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: The `isc-dhcp-server` failed to start, so stopping it is unnecessary. Uninstall or just don't `start` it again? Up to you. Please see `https://netplan.io` and `https://netplan.io/examples`.

Comment: My steps are outlined in the question, the links just show my references. I started fresh (reinstall of ics-dhcp) and corrected the path of the interface config file to /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server. The error persists, as if no interface is recognized or the dhcp.conf is not run correctly and therefore the interface is not touched. From the error message I can only guess that the dhcp.conf file is not parsed correctly, but every iteration I found on the web looks like this

Comment: interfaces is specified in `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`, as you have done. If it is the server, it needs to have a static IP address. In 20.04 you should not be using a `/etc/network/interfaces` file.